# What are the different clipboard/register types in gVim?

Tags: vim, clipboard

[image: picture of what gvim displays when I type <code>:reg</code>]

How are l and c register types different? Are they multiple clipboards? I'm not sure if this is a windows thing or gVim thing. Correct my question if needed. Typing :reg in gVim shows me the content of each register (as explained in the vim help on the left).

Comment: Simply read `:h :reg`

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers